# Footer shows bullets in third column

Tags: footer, default.xml

How do I remove the bullets in the second picture?
I have a website and the footer looks like this:

[image]

But now I want to change the third column, but in the third column suddenly appears bullets in front of the link:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? It's the file "default.xml" in "magento_theme".
I removed the repetition of the columns in the code to simplify.
The coding for this piece of footer is:

```
 <referenceContainer name="footer.content.left.wrapper">

        <referenceBlock name="footer.left.content.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">K1-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="footer.content.left.ul">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="footer.content.left.block"
                   after="-"
                   template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">

                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K1R1-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K1R1L-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="footer.content.center.left">

            <referenceBlock name="footer.left.center.content.title">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">K2-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

            <container name="footer.content.left.center.ul" label="Footer links list" htmlTag="ul" after="-">

                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                       after="-"
                       name="footer.content.left.center.block"
                       template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">

                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K2R1-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K2R1L-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                 </block>
            </container>

        </referenceContainer>


        <container name="footer.content.center.right" label="Footer Content Center Right" htmlTag="ul"
                   htmlClass="c-footer-item c-footer-item__contact col-4-12">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer.right.center.content.title"
                   before="-" template="Magento_Theme::text.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">K3-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                    <argument name="tag" xsi:type="string">h3</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">c-footer-item__links__title</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K3R1-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">K3R1L-DE-NL-FR-BE</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
        </container>

    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Just use `list-style:none` CSS

Comment: Like: .class-selector{
  list-style: none;
}

Comment: where in the xlm code you want to place this?

Comment: Brother, it is CSS code. you need to add in your custom style css file!

Comment: Thnx! I put it in the c-footer-item c-footer-item__contact col-4-12 and i worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom style css file
Do changes, in the div that shows the bullet(you can use inspect element tool also of browser) and then add some css class like
`<div class="my_css_class">` , then you can remove the bullets by adding this code

```
.my_css_class{ list-style: none; }
```

in your custom css style file.